# How to determine which control was Clicked and contextMenuStrp appeared?

Tags: c#, controls, click

I've assigned a contextMenuStrip to the same contextual menu property of two ListBox controls.
I would like to determine which of them has activated the contextual menu.
Because I have to change some entries depending on which control was clicked at runtime.

```
        private void copyNotesToClipboardStripMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ListBox cntrl = conMenuNotes.SourceControl as ListBox;
            //cntrl does not contain info about which ListBox was clicked :((

            //check which ListBox was clicked
            if (/*oneListBox*/)
            {
                 //do something                    
            }
            if(/*anotherLiskBox*/)
            {    
                //do something
            }              
        }
```

As i read another posts it should be the name of the clicked control in the **Label** property.

I see that **cntrl.Label** is **null**

What i'm doing wrong ? 
Advice me how to resolve this ambiguity.
Thank you!

Comment: maybe should implement in another way to be able to determine which control activated the contextMenu ...

Comment: Just compare, if (ctrl == listBox1).  Or use the Tag property on the list box controls to give them custom data you can find back later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a result that works fine for me

```
        private void copyNotesToClipboardStripMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ToolStripMenuItem menuItem = sender as ToolStripMenuItem;
            if (menuItem != null)
            {
                ContextMenuStrip calendarMenu = menuItem.Owner as ContextMenuStrip;
                if (calendarMenu != null)
                {
                    Control controlSelected = calendarMenu.SourceControl;
                }
            }
        }
```

The property **Name** of **controlSelected** object contains the name of control which has activated the contextual menu.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of assigning the menu to the two controls, use the right click event on the controls to execute a function like this

- set a global variable to point to the control that's just been clicked
- display the menu you want at the mouse coordinates
- now in your `copyNotesToClipboardStripMenu_Click` method you can access the global variable that's storing the clicked control

Also don't forget to set the global to `null` after you're done with it and to make sure you use `lock` when using it.

Comment: Thank you for advice, but I think this is not a good practice. Easily I can add two contextMenuStrip for each ListBox, but also, is not a good practice...